# TortoiseSVN made my windows stop working soon after log in

Tags: windows-7, tortoisesvn

I'm running an Windows 7 Home Basic in a Megaware machine with 8GB RAM, intel Core i5 2.9 GHz (x64), 1 TB of Hard Disk.

The problem is: since today, when i tried to update a project from an SVN repository at google code with TortoiseSVN 1.7.1 (for 64-bit systems) at the same time i opened the Eclipse (Indigo for Java EE), the windows just stops working. No error messages, i just can't do nothing. I can still move my mouse, but all the functions of the windows simply do not respond (i tried ctrl+alt+del , alt+f4, win, win+e, win+r...). I'm acessing via safe mode (with network).

I tried also to uninstall the Tortoise (had to find out how to turn on the MSIServer on), but even after uninstalling it, the problem continues. Can the Tortoise have damaged one of my system's file? Reinstall the windows is my last option, btw.

Answer (score 0):

It might have, but I doubt it.  It could also be something else that's been installed since then.  Instead of reinstalling windows, go into your Start Menu, and select "System Restore".  If you have a restore point defined from before you started experiencing problems, that could be a good way to get back to what you had without a full reinstall.

Comment: Well, i restored it back to a critical windows update, 7 days ago (and one day before installing the tortoiseSVN), and it seemed to work. But when i tried to open the Firefox, everything started again, and now it is worse, even before my desktop loads, the windows stops. Curiously, it only happens on normal mode. I've already uninstalled a bunch of programs that could be behind this mystery, but with no luck. What unsettles me the most is that i can't even find out where the problem is!